# Can I share URL to facebook with gif as image?

Tags: facebook, image, gif, sharing

I know we can share URL to facebook with custom image such as jpg or png, but is it possible to use gif as share image? I tried to implement with the following code and facebook used only the first frame of the gif as the sharing image.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.picsymag.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/funny-gif17.gif" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is supported yet.

Comment: This guy makes it work: http://voidcanvas.com/how-to-display-gif-thumbnail-while-sharing-the-webpage-in-facebook/
However, I tried it for myself and can't seem to replicate... I'd love an answer!